# Using RefreshDatabase shows the Driver not found error

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am Trying to write tests in laravel, i have been doing this for some time and it has been working well. With this new project, i am supposed to use TDD still and the Refresh Database. When i include use RefreshDatabase, i get an error that i have not been getting with the other projects i have been working on. What could be the problem.

code i am testing.

```
class ParentsTest extends TestCase
{
    use RefreshDatabase;

    /** @test */
    public function createParentTest(){
        $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
        $response = $this->post('/create-parent',[
            'fname' => 'Julius',
            'lname' => 'Ssemakula',
            'contact' => '256702913454'
        ]);
        $this->assertDatabaseHas('Parents', ['fname' => 'Julius']);
    }
}
```

the error I get is

> 1) Tests\Feature\ParentsTest::createParentTest
>   Illuminate\Database\QueryException: could not find driver (SQL: PRAGMA
>   foreign_keys = ON;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install the appropriate driver for the database you are using. If you are on Linux:

First find out which version of PHP you are running using `php --version`. I'll use `php7.3` for demonstration purposes.

For MySQL:

```
sudo apt install php7.3-mysql
```

For SQLite:

```
sudo apt install php7.3-sqlite
```

For PostgreSQL:

```
sudo apt install php7.3-pgsql
```

After installing the appropriate drivers, your tests should work.

Comment: Tengo todas las extensiones instaladas para PDO y aun me da error, lo extraño es que la base de datos que estoy usando es postgresql pero con las pruebas unitarias me da error con sqlite

Comment: Es posible que esté utilizando funciones que no están disponibles en SQLite. (Google Translated)